# CSS transition and property delay not working on mouseout

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've made a hidden vertical menu, which show on hover/active. I'm using the `transition` property with a delay.

- When mouse is hover, menu is showing with the delay
- When mouse is out, menu is going/draw back, but without any delay.

```css
li {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul ul {
  max-height: 0em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul > li:hover ul,
ul > li:active ul {
  max-height: 10em;
  transition: 1000ms all ease 500ms;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Option1
    <ul>
      <li>OptionA</li>
      <li>OptionB</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Option2</li>
</ul>
```

How can I have a delay/duration, moving back to initial value ?

PS: I can't use JavaScript.

Comment: Side note, you might want to add `:focus` because hover events don't exist on touch devices.

Comment: Have you tried to use the separate css for delay? (Transition-delay) and with All The necessary prefixes (-WebKit-, -moz-, -o-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the transition to the element, not the state. When the state is over (leaving the element with your mouse) the CSS takes no more effect.

Updated. Snippet now opens instantly and has a closing delay of 2000ms. By increasing the hover state delay you can increase the opening delay.

```css
li {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul ul {
  max-height: 0em;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 1000ms all ease 2000ms;
     -moz-transition: 1000ms all ease 2000ms;
      -ms-transition: 1000ms all ease 2000ms;
       -o-transition: 1000ms all ease 2000ms;
          transition: 1000ms all ease 2000ms;
}

ul > li:hover ul,
ul > li:focus ul,
ul > li:active ul {
  max-height: 10em;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
     -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
      -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
       -o-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Option1
    <ul>
      <li>OptionA</li>
      <li>OptionB</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Option2</li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** You can also use `transition: 1000ms max-height ease 500ms;` in this case for slightly better performance. Not significant on a single transition but they might add up.

Comment: You're missing the part in which OP wishes to have a delay when _switching back from hover to normal_ :-).

Comment: Did some improvements to the snippet.

Comment: Cheers, this answer is now the best answer from all options.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `transition` to the element when not hovered too. Try the snippet below.

```css
li {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul ul {
  max-height: 0em;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 400ms all ease 500ms;
}
ul > li:hover ul,
ul > li:active ul {
  max-height: 10em;
  transition: 1000ms all ease 500ms;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Option1
    <ul>
      <li>OptionA</li>
      <li>OptionB</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Option2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the `transition` to the original properties, and you are good to go, because you can add a `transition-delay` there. This is why you should specify both the state, and the original elements. Because you wish to include the delay only on exiting the `:hover`/`:active`/`:focus` state.

```css
li {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul ul {
  max-height: 0em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul > li ul,
ul > li ul {
  transition: all ease 500ms;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}
ul > li:hover ul,
ul > li:active ul,
ul > li:focus ul {
  max-height: 10em;
  transition: 1000ms all ease 500ms;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Option1
    <ul>
      <li>OptionA</li>
      <li>OptionB</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Option2</li>
</ul>
```